# react change props massive error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm new in react and may be doing something wrong.

I have one main parent component and his child and child of main's child (child 2).

main->child1->child 2

i send data to child1 by props.items:

**main.js**

```
  <child1 items={this.state.lst}>
```

Then i resend it to child2:

**child1.js**

```
    search(res){
    this.props.items=res;        
  }

<Find dataChild2={this.props.items} findData={this.search.bind(this)}/>
```

In child 2 i changed this data and call child1 function search:

**child2.js**

```
  someFunc(){
  //manipulate with this.props.dataChild2 and write it in result;
  this.props.findData(result);
  }
```

I just want to rewrite this.props.items in search function but have an error:

```
×
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'items' of object '#<Object>'
```

How i can change it correctly ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update the props, they are immutable. If you want the manipulated result value in your top parent, rather having the search method in child1, move it to parent and catch the result in search method there -

Parent -

```
<child1 items={this.state.lst} getData={this.search.bind(this)}>
```

Child1 -

```
<Find dataChild2={this.props.items} findData={this.props.getData.bind(this)}/>
```

Child2 -

```
someFunc(){
 this.props.findData(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this:

```
this.props.items=res;
```

Props and stats are non-mutable objects. Just create a new item inside the state of the component:

```
this.setState({newItems: res});
...
<Find dataChild2={this.state.items} findData={this.search.bind(this)}/>
```